# Dose exist closed form for $ I=\int_{x=0}^{\alpha}x^{n-1}e^{-x\beta}\gamma(m,(\alpha-x)\zeta) $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

A am working with gamma random variable. While I am simplify the derived expression, I stuck in the following integral.

Let $n$ and $m$  be positive integers and $x, \alpha, \zeta$ $\beta$ real numbers.

I would like to simplify the following integral $I$

$$
I=\int_{x=0}^{\alpha}x^{n-1}e^{-x\beta}\gamma\Big(m,(\alpha-x)\zeta\Big)dx,
$$

where $\gamma(n,x)$ is the incmplet lower gamma function define by

$$
\gamma(n,x)=\int_{t=0}^{x}t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt.
$$

Thanks

Comment: Please, define $\gamma$.

Comment: Ok one moment please

Comment: # Spenser  I hope you can help me.

Comment: I try series representation $\gamma(n,x)=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{n+p}}{n!(n+p)}$ when I am using matlab  dose not converge for all numbers. and when I am increase nth serie my PC take days and dose not complete the operation?

Comment: So there's no restrictions on $\alpha,\beta,\zeta$? They can be any real numbers?

Comment: yes real and lets say positive

Comment: Unifortinutly I am goin out now and I will go back later.

Comment: Not that The first problem is to find the CDF sum of two random variables. I think to use the Laplace transform to get the CDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to evaluate:

$$I=\int_0^{\alpha}x^{n-1}e^{-\beta x} \int_0^{(\alpha-x)\zeta}t^{m-1}e^{-t}dt dx$$

First, let's make the following substitution:

$$x=\alpha y$$

Then we have:

$$I=\alpha^n \int_0^1 y^{n-1}e^{-b y} \int_0^{c(1-y)}t^{m-1}e^{-t}dt dy$$

Where $b=\alpha \beta$, $c=\alpha \zeta $, which allows us to reduce the number of parameters.

Now let's try to do the same with the other variable.

$$t=c(1-y)u$$

$$I=\alpha^n c^m \int_0^1 y^{n-1} (1-y)^m e^{-b y} \int_0^1 u^{m-1}e^{-c(1-y)u}du dy$$

Maybe a series expansion of the second integral could work:

$$I=\alpha^n c^m \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k c^k}{k!} \int_0^1 y^{n-1} (1-y)^{m+k} e^{-b y} \int_0^1 u^{m+k-1}du dy$$

$$I=\alpha^n c^m \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k c^k}{k!(m+k)} \int_0^1 y^{n-1} (1-y)^{m+k} e^{-b y} dy$$

The last integral gives us:

$$\int_0^1 y^{n-1} (1-y)^{m+k} e^{-b y} dy=(n-1)! (m+k)! \, _1\tilde{F}_1(n;n+m+k+1;-b)$$

Where $\, _1\tilde{F}_1$ is a generalized regularized hypergeometric function.

In this way we obtain a (formal) series:

> $$I=(n-1)! \alpha^n c^m \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k (m+k-1)! c^k}{k!} \, _1\tilde{F}_1(n;n+m+k+1;-b)$$

The question of convergence is a different animal, however I can certainly say that there are values of $b,c$ such that the series converges.

Here are a couple of examples in Mathematica (I use my third integral expression to compare with the series):

```
In[384]:= n = 6; 
m = 8; 
b = 4; 
c = 4; 
NIntegrate[y^(n - 1)*(1 - y)^m*Exp[(-b)*y]*u^(m - 1)*Exp[(-c)*(1 - y)*u], {y, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
N[(n - 1)!*Sum[((-c)^k*(m + k - 1)!*Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[n, n + m + k + 1, -b])/k!, {k, 0, 100}], 10]
Out[388]= 1.719760455*10^-7
Out[389]= 1.719721615*10^-7

In[415]:= $MaxExtraPrecision =1000;
n = 3; 
m = 11; 
b = 1/5; 
c = 1/3; 
NIntegrate[y^(n - 1)*(1 - y)^m*Exp[(-b)*y]*u^(m - 1)*Exp[(-c)*(1 - y)*u], {y, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
N[(n - 1)!*Sum[((-c)^k*(m + k - 1)!*Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[n, n + m + k + 1, -b])/k!, {k, 0, 100}], 10]
Out[420]= 0.00006265635078
Out[421]= 0.00006265694467
```

In conclusion, this series is obviously complicated, and it's better to evaluate the integral numerically. I'm not sure a closed form exists at all, though of course, we can try other ways to derive it.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your effort. I will use this expression and I hop It converge  for my paramtre. But can we use $\gamma(n,x)=n!\left(1-e^x\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^p}{p!}\right)$.

Comment: @Monir, why not just use numerical methods for the integral? This series is not very good

Comment: I would also wait before accepting this answer if I were you, maybe something better comes along

Comment: I am writing PAPER for IEEE so I need close formula.

Comment: I have eqution but I need to find where it converge. An author in paper after driven his expression and put it in form of $u_i$, hi compute $ \lim_{i\to\infty} \left|\frac{u_{i+1}}{u_i}\right|\leq 1$. But in my expression  I will get some thing like  $\frac{\gamma(n+1,x)}{\gamma(n,x)}$, how we simplify it?

Comment: @Monir, there might be some identities, I suggest looking up Wikipedia page for incomplete gamma

Comment: Ok i will try to find somethings.

Comment: @Monir, about your first comment: sure, you can use your formula as well, maybe you'll get a better expression that way